# catkin build fails because PythonInterp cannot be found

Tags: ros, catkin, python3, ros-noetic

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 using ros noetic.

When trying to run `catkin build <package_name>` I get the following error message:

```
   CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/python.cmake:4 
    (find_package): By not providing "FindPythonInterp.cmake" in 
    CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package 
    configuration file provided by "PythonInterp", but CMake did not 
    find one.

   Could not find a package configuration file provided by 
    "PythonInterp" (requested version 3) with any of the following names:

    PythonInterpConfig.cmake
    pythoninterp-config.cmake

   Add the installation prefix of "PythonInterp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH 
    or set "PythonInterp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above 
    files. If "PythonInterp" provides a separate development package or 
    SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I have used `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash` and `source devel/setup.bash` to source my catkin workspace. When building another package that is in the same src folder of my catkin workspace, the build is successful. I have tried many different solutions from people with similar problems, but nothing has worked so far. VSCode detects a problem in my `CMakeLists.txt` file in the first line:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  pcl_ros
  rosbag
)
```

This is the error message from vscode:

```
   CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package):By not providing 
    "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake 
    to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but CMake 
    did not find one.

   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" 
    with any of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

   Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
    "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If 
    "catkin" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it 
    has been installed.
```

Answer (score 2):

"FindPythonInterp.cmake" has been deprecated for a long time, and is removed in more recent cmake versions:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FindPythonInterp.html

The page recommends: "Use FindPython3, FindPython2 or FindPython instead."

Note: it is likely that you caused this problem for yourself by installing a more recent version of cmake than is provided by the ubuntu-20 repository. Most developers assume you are using the ubuntu-released version of a tool: cmake 3.16.3 in this case. If you were using the recommended version of cmake, you would not have run into this build error.